# Как сделать адаптивным блок с текстом при экране 400px?

Tags: css3, flexbox

```css
.bar_inner2 {
  width: 512px;
  margin-left: 138px;
}

.bar_inner2 div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 25px;
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1BB55D;
}

.bar_inner2 div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 552px;
  height: 66px;
  font-family: PT Serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #1E2529;
}

.bar_inner2 div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 582px;
  height: 122px;
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #849299;
}

.bar_inner2 div:nth-child(4) {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1E2529;
}

.bar_inner2 div:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #1E2529;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar_inner2">
  <div>100% натуральное</div>
  <div>Масло торговой марки «Вiтаю»</div>
  <div>Подсолнечное масло «Вiтаю» разливается на Полтавском маслоэкстракционном заводе - одном из крупнейших предприятий отрасли, которое входит в состав компании KERNEL. На заводе установлено самое современное оборудование, позволяющее изготавливать рафинированное
    дезодорированное масло </div>
  <div>о нас</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: прикрепите стили

Comment: как то так.... .

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen (max-width: 400px) {
    .bar_inner2 {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .bar_inner2 div:nth-child(1) {
        height: auto;
    }
    .bar_inner2 div:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .bar_inner2 div:nth-child(3) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: еще добавить в head -> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> если его там нет

Comment: Спасибо Бро) Как просто, почему я такое не сделал)